# Найти одинаковые элементы двух массивов

Tags: java, массивы

Создал два массива, которые сам же прописываю с клавиатуры. Мне надо найти одинаковые элементы этих массивов и вывести их, допустим, в третий массив:

```java
public class Main {
    protected static int[] number1;
    protected static int[] number2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("количество массива");
        int size = input.nextInt();
        number1 = new int[size];
        System.out.println("ввести элементы массива");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            number1[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Сам массив: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(number1[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("заполним второй массив ");
        number2 = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            number2[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Сам массив: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(number2[i] + " ");
        }
        // тут я должен начать их сравнивать, но из-за
        // множества новой информации, с таким вроде бы
        // простым вопросом, я через гугл не разобрался 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь все очень просто. Сначала вы должны выбрать любой массив (например, number1), по которому поочередно будете сравнивать со всеми элементами второго массива, если вы найдете совпадение, то вложенный цикл отменяем командой break(). Вообще это общий случай, который не оптимизирован: если у вас допустим в number1 будут одинаковые элементы, то вы все равно будете сравнивать элементы другого массива.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number1.length; i++) 
{
    int a = number[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < number2.length; j++) 
    {
        if (a == number2[j]) 
        {
           System.out.println(a);
           break();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: согласен, элементарно, благодарю)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, или не изобретать велосипед и воспользоваться `java.util.Array.equals(number1, number2)`

Comment: Хотел сначала также написать, но подумал, что лучше показать наглядно:)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно именно через массивы, но это топорно не спорю.

```
public static int[] sameNumbersInArrays(int[] number1,int[] number2) {
       int[] number3 = new int[number1.length];
       int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < number1.length ; i++) {
            if(number1[i] == number2[i]) {
                number3[count] = number1[i];
                count++;
            }
        }

        int[] number4 = new int[count];
        System.arraycopy(number3,0,number4, 0, count);
        return number4;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуемся "резиновым" массивом `ArrayList<T>`, где `T` - тип элементов, который хранит массив. Пусть `arr` - переменная типа `ArrayList<Integer>`. Отмечу, что в угловых скобках не могут быть примитивные типы - только ссылочные. `int` заменяется на `Integer`, `double` - на `Double`, `long` - на `Long` и т. д. (напоминаю, что регистр имеет значение). Этими типами можно работать как с обычными переменными.

Для нашего массива будут справедливы следующие утверждения:

1. `arr.add(a)` - добавляет в конец массива элемент `a`. Он должен конвертироваться в тип `T`. В нашем случае - в `Integer`. `int` в `Integer` легко преобразуется
2. `arr.contains(a)` - проверяет, есть ли элемент `a` в нашем массиве. Если это так, получаем `true`, в ином случае - `false`
3. `arr.sort(null)` - сортирует элементы массива по возрастанию. Или по другому правилу, если его указать вместо `null`

Таким образом, данная задача решается таким образом:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i: number1)
            //начинаем перебирать элементы первого массива
            for(int j: number2)
                //начинаем перебирать элементы второго массива
                if(!arr.contains(i) && i == j)
                    arr.add(i);
        //если элементы совпадают, записываем его в наш массив, если его там ещё нет
        arr.sort(null);
        //сортируем общие элементы. Для удобства
        System.out.println("Общие элементы");
        for(int i: arr) System.out.print(i + " ");
```

P. S. На самом деле ArrayList не массив, а список.

Comment: "ArrayList не массив, а список." - вы исходный код вообще смотрели, выдвигая такое утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант решения:

```java
int[] numberEq = null;
for (int n : number1) {
    if (Arrays.asList(number2).contains(n)) {
        if (numberEq == null) {
            numberEq = new int[1];
            numberEq[0] = n;
        } else {
            numberEq = Arrays.copyOf(numberEq, numberEq.length + 1);
            numberEq[numberEq.length - 1] = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ищем повторяющиеся элементы в двух массивах и собираем в третий массив:

```java
int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 8, 5};
int[] arr2 = {3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 8, 2, 2};

int[] arr3 = Stream.of(arr1, arr2)
        // выкидываем из каждого массива поворяющиеся
        // элементы и объединяем в один Stream<Integer> 
        .flatMap(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().boxed())
        // группируем в карту по количеству вхождений
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()))
        // обходим карту
        .entrySet().stream()
        // количество больше одного
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
        // получаем сами элементы
        .map(e -> e.getKey())
        // получаем 'int' значения элементов 
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        // собираем в массив
        .toArray();

// выводим массив повторяющихся элементов
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3)); // [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```